# How to perform a redirect inside a Promise inside a fetch()

Tags: redirect, ecmascript-6, promise, fetch, es6-promise

Is this the proper way to redirect inside a Promise? Does this cause any adverse effects? Possible memory leak?

```
      .then(function (response ){
            if( response.redirected){
              location.href = response.url;
            }
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function (record) {
            console.log("record update:",record);
                onRecordUpdate(record);
        })
```

Comment: It wont cause a memory leak, because you're loading a new page which will discard the current pages state.

Comment: I don't see how this is different between being inside a promise or elsewhere

Comment: At the point of redirection, does that break the chain and resolves the last existing Promise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    .then(function (response ){
      if( response.redirected){
        location.href = response.url;
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (record) {
      console.log("record update:",record);
      onRecordUpdate(record);
    })
```

Basically, it will not run the codes that after location change. Sometimes it can works if the browser gets slow but theorically it shouldn't work. So my opinion you should run **onRecordUpdate(record)** function before location change to avoid any silent error.

As @nils says, you will not get any memory leak because it will refresh the page and state will be cleaned.